# unable to create directory in laravel 5.1 when upload image?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Error : Unable to create the "http:/localhost/shopping/public/src/img/" directory

```
my code :
$imageName = $product->id . '.' . 
        $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file('image')->move(
        url().'/public/src/img/', $imageName
        );
```

Comment: `unable to create directory` which directory ? `img` ?

Comment: check if permission is set correctly

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-public-path) helper, not `url()`:

```
->move(public_path('src/img/'.$imageName));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was little bit different. I am using laravel 5.5.
If i will use below code on my local system, then its work properly

```
$destinationPath = public_path('images\post');
$image->move($destinationPath, $inputimg);
```

But on production same above code throwing error.
 ***Unable to create the "/var/www/mycar/public/images\post" directory***

If someone have same issue then change **'images\post'** to **'images/post'**